# How to create a hand with 13 playing cards in it

Tags: python

I was given a project in computer science, however I can't figure out how to get 13 cards into my hand. There is a memory error in the hand class, but I can't figure out why, it isn't putting 13 cards in each hand. Here is my code so far:

```
#Keshav Ramesh
#Project 8

import random

class card:         
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit=suit
        self.value=value

    #methods
    def printer(self):
        print("{0}  {1}".format(self.suit, self.value))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if(self.value == other.value):
            return self.suit < other.suit
        elif (self.value != other.value):
            return self.value < other.value
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return not(self<other)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Suit: " + str(self.suit) + " value: " + str(self.value)

class deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=[]
        self.load()
        random.shuffle(self.x)

    def load(self):
        for i in range(1, 5):
            for j in range(2, 14):
                self.x.append(card(i, j))

    def deal(self):
        return self.x.pop()

p = deck() 
class hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=[]
        self.hand_count=0
        while len(self.x) != 13:
            self.x.append(p.deal())

    def accept(self, a):
        self.x.append(a)
        self.hand_count= self.hand_count + 1

    def play(self):
        self.hand_count = self.hand_count - 1
        return self.x.pop() 

    def handPrinter(self):
        while len(self.x) != 0: 
            result = (self.pop())
            print("{0}  {1}".format(result.suit, result.value))
```

Comment: `hand_count` seems to be equivalent to `len(x)`, so you could save yourself some trouble by not tracking `hand_count` manually. You can simplify `hand.__init__` by saying `self.x = [p.deal() for _ in range(13)]`

Comment: I don't get an error when running this. Please write the code so the error is reproduced.

Comment: When do you try to add cards to your hand class. I took your code and created a hand and did `my.accept(p.deal())` and it added cards to my hand.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
result = (self.pop())
```

in the handPrinter method maybe you meant to do

```
result = (self.x.pop())
```

That was causing an error when executing your code. Also, in the `__init__` method of Card class you should ident `self.suit = suit` and `self.value = value`.

Other than that, by adding

```
h = hand()
h.handPrinter()
```

at the end, everything seems to be working fine to me.